# find point with equidistant from two points

Tags: geometry

Suppose there is given two point  $A=(-4;-2)$ and $B=(3,2)$  we have to find  such  $C$ point on 
$OY$ axis, such that

a) $C$ is equidistant from $A$ and $B$

b) $ACB$  spline must be  minimum.

As I know for solving part (a), we should  write equation of line, which is perpendicular of $AB$ segment and goes through it's midpoint as well, in a)  case  coordinates of C is  $(0,y)$

midpoint of $AB=(-0.5,0)$,so equation would be
$y=k(x+0.5)$  where $k$ is equal to $-7/4$,because the slope of segment $AB$ is $4/7$ and we know that  for perpendicular  lines,$\text{slope}_1*\text{slope}_2=-1$, so we get that $y=-7/4*(x+0.5)$.
 If $x=0$ then $y=-0.5*7/4=-7/8$, so I have got that for a $C$ coordinates are $(0,-7/8)$.
Am i correct for part (a)?

As for (b)  I think that I can take symmetry  point of  $B'$  related to $B$ along
so that $B'=(-3,2)$, equation of   $AB'$ would be
$y+2=4(x+4)$ or $y=4*x+14$  coordinated of  $C$ is if we put $x=0$  we get  $(0,14)$.
Am i right? please help me to check my work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing your method is corretc.A short method to solve a) is : if $I$ is the middle of $[AB]$  then  $C$   is  determined  by  :  $\overrightarrow{CI}.\overrightarrow{AB}=0$ and $x_C=0$

Comment: @ dato: I want help you about  the  question b)  but  I   don't  know  what is 'spline'   definition . If  you can define this  I try to  help  you.

Comment: please check at internet  if you are interested

Comment: I'm not talking about the general definition of the word but the context of your exercises
 I still know the meaning of the word in general

Comment: spline in my question refers geometry figure,which   can be  represented by points connected or  not connected,sorry for such explanation,but is  like a not connected ordering of points

Comment: it is  example of spline http://ka.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%83%9B%E1%83%A0%E1%83%90%E1%83%95%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%99%E1%83%A3%E1%83%97%E1%83%AE%E1%83%94%E1%83%93%E1%83%98 here it is connected